# On Slick.js how to calculate currently visible slides?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

My case is I'm showing some photos with variable width on a 100% div so it adjusts to the browser width. I set slick.js in centerMode and now I want to style the 'edge' images that are just partially visible.

For this I need to know which slides are visible or not.

I know if you use slidesToShow to the right number you can style the css of 'slick-active' but the problem is that my container total width depends on user screen size and also my slides have variable width so I can't know how many slides to show.

How can I calculate easily what slides are currently visible or not? (for me the partial visible should be marked as hidden)

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mj1ds6fk/)

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  focusOnSelect: true,
  centerMode: true,

  centerPadding: '10%',
  slidesToShow: 2,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  variableWidth: true
});
```

```css
.slider div {
  padding: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.css">

<div class="slider">

  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I write code here to get current active(showing) slide list, and get count, and do some action when slide is change: [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mj1ds6fk/1/)

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  focusOnSelect: true,
  centerMode: true,

  centerPadding: '10%',
  slidesToShow: 2,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  variableWidth: true,
});

doMyAction($(".slider").slick('slickCurrentSlide'));
$(".slider").on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction){
  doMyAction($(".slider").slick('slickCurrentSlide'));
});

function doMyAction(currentSlick){
  // your acction for current slick
   console.log('Current Slick:', currentSlick);
}

console.log(getActiveSlickLength());
function getActiveSlickLength()
{
 return $('.slick-active').length;
}

console.log(getActiveSlickIndexList());
function getActiveSlickIndexList()
{
 var indexes = [];
  $.each($('.slick-active'), function(key, value){
   indexes[key] = $(value).data('slick-index');
  });
  
  return indexes;
}
```

```css
.slider div {
  padding: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.css">


<div class="slider">

  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200"></div>

</div>
```

> I use swipe event to do action when change active slick, so that you
>   detect or update list on every swipe to your action, and other option
>   can be access, or updated as you want dependence of swipe or any other
>   code idea.

Note: This solution will return current active slick slides as you want, but not make sure if its optimal solution with slick.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make the right styling for the major breakpoints using slick.js responsive method. I had to do that recently and on some breakpoints I had to turn off the centerMode and change how many images are visible so you will control how many images are visible at all times. I hope that helps if you need to see an example of the code I used please let me know!